# Is there a way to do sequential bindings in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to use the `binding` macro, but want it to be sequential like in `let`.

I guess I can write it like this...

```
(binding [a 1]
  (binding [b (inc a)]
    (println b)))
```

...but there's gotta be a better way.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(defmacro binding* [bindings & body]
  (reduce (fn [acc [x y]]
            `(binding [~x ~y] ~acc))
          `(do ~@body)
          (reverse (partition 2 bindings))))

user> (declare ^:dynamic a ^:dynamic b)
#'user/b
user> (binding* [a 1 b (inc a)] [a b])
[1 2]

user> (macroexpand-1 '(binding* [a 1 b (inc a)] [a b]))
(clojure.core/binding [a 1]
 (clojure.core/binding [b (inc a)] 
  (do [a b])))
```

Comment: +1, though do you have any idea why binding wasn't implemented this way in the first instance?

Comment: +1 also. A nice illustration of how macros can correct limitations of the language.

Comment: @mikera Maybe because `binding` is altering vars, so it has to worry more about thread safety?  Just a guess, no idea really.

Comment: I wrote a response that I deleted, as the more I thought about it, the more I think the requested behavior is odd, given what's happening under the covers. The `binding` function is mostly just a wrapper around the `hash-map` constructor, and given that that constructor doesn't work this way, with later values referencing earlier values by key, I suspect the library authors didn't think it made sense to even want this behavior. Regardless, having come from Common Lisp myself, where `let*` would have done the trick, I am still sympathetic.